# Converting 2 longs to corresponding byte[], and combining with a delimeter in between

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

I need to convert 2 longs to corresponding byte[], and then combine them with a delimeter in between. What is the most performant way to do this ? (I need to store resultant byte[] in the database.)

```
         like I have-
         long a=5324565343L  
         long b=423456L
```

then I want the byte[] representation of :-

```
         5324565343-423456
```

**EDIT**: Couldnt understand what was actually unclear but still for clarification, 
I intially have 2 `long`(s) & I just want a byte[] of their concatenated form.

Comment: your question is unclear.  As you can see, @jzd and @ilya have interpreted it quite differently, and (IMO) both are valid interpretations.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: do you want the byte representation of the string "5324565343-423456" ... or a 9 byte sequence consisting of 4 bytes for `a`, 1 byte of a `'-'` character and 4 bytes for `b`.  Can you see the difference?  Can you see that @jzd answers one, and @ilya answers the other?

Comment: What is unclear is what representation you want in byte form.  You want the bytes for the string "5324565343-423456"?  That's @jzd's answer.  You want 8 bytes for the first long, then two bytes for the delimiter, then 8 bytes for the second long?  That's @ilya's answer.  They reach a completely different result.

Comment: either works for me ..whichever is more fast!

Comment: reason why I am asking for fast is because, I am putting this piece of code to get the primary keys(resulting from concatenation of two longs) of my NoSQL database. So each time any row needs to be accessed this is called, thus it is a most heavily used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ByteBuffer from java.nio.ByteBuffer:

```
    long a = 5324565343L;
    long b = 423456L;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[18];
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    buffer.putLong(a);
    buffer.putChar('-');
    buffer.putLong(b);
```

Comment: Or put((byte) '-') if you just want a byte.

Comment: cool..this seems to be better way then string conversions, etc.. Could let me know why bytebuffer has been specifically used for this purpose. Thanks so much!

Comment: Because it works as fast as you would do it manually by converting long to bytes. And I think that you do not need a delimeter.

Comment: I am using these as keys of my database. Thus these need to be unique uptil the two longs I am providing, are unique. I was adding delimeter so that the result remains unique. But I guess in your solution I am always getting fixed no. of bytes(irrespective of how small a no is, relative to Max.Long) thus I may not need that now, perhaps !

Answer (score 1):

Concantenate them and call `getBytes()` on the resulting String.

Something like:

```
(a + "-" + b).getBytes();
```

Comment: doesn't that return the sequence of bytes of the String `5324565343-423456` in the platform's default charset? Is that what my almost-homonym Marcos is asking?

Comment: @Marcos, You cannot cast a `long` to a `String` but you can add/append the toString(long) of their values.

Comment: yes..so I dont think this toString conversion & then appends would be the most performant way to go, I guess!? I need to place it with a really high performance code in my application.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to place it with a really high performance code in my application.

No you don't.

Consider this:

- The time you will save by avoiding the creation of Strings is likely to be less than a microsecond.
- The time taken to perform an SQL insert over a JDBC connection is likely to be measured in milliseconds.

In other words optimizing this particular operation is likely to have negligible effect on the *overall* performance of your application.

Comment: perhaps why I think that it needs to more performant is because, I am putting this piece of code to get the primary keys(which result from concatenation of two longs) of my NoSQL database. So each time any row needs to be accessed this is called, thus it is a most heavily used & i needed to send just the byte[] to DB not string.

Comment: ..and negligible may become significant in case of heavy duty code.

Comment: The only way that the code could become significant is if you took the database (SQL, NOSQL, whatever) out of the picture entirely.